# SQL: Select a string_id that only occurs once per page_id

Tags: sql

Here is my table:

```
 page_id | string_id |       content
       1 |  terms_en | etc text lorem ipsum
       1 |  terms_es | etc espanol lorem    
       2 |   tabtext | stuff text lorem etc
       3 |  veh_name | etc stuff letters lala
       4 |   btn_txt | text for a button etc
       4 | alert_txt | text for an alert etc lala
       5 |  page_cnt | lala pagecontent etc lala
```

I need to select all of the `page_id`s where the `page_id` only has one `string_id` associated with it

In essence, I am trying to return the `page_id`s: `2`, `3`, and `5` from this table.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT page_id, string_id
FROM lang_strings
WHERE string_id != 'content'
GROUP BY string_id, page_id
HAVING count(string_id) < 2 AND count(page_id) < 2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
SELECT page_id, count(distinct string_id) 
FROM lang_strings
WHERE string_id != 'content'
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(distinct string_id) = 1
```

Using `distinct` within the `count()` handles the case where there's multiple rows with the *same* `string_id`, which of course would count as there being just *one* value (that occurs many times).

You haven't specified which database you're using, so you may likely find that you don't have to *select* `count(distinct string_id)` for the query to work

Comment: Haha I forgot I put string_id != 'content in this post. I saw it in your query and I was like "WTF HOW DOES HE KNOW THAT"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT page_id
     , max(string_id) as string_id
FROM lang_strings
WHERE string_id != 'content'
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(page_id) = 1
```

If you only need the `page_id`, you can remove the second column using the MAX function.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
SELECT page_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        page_id,
        string_id
    FROM lang_strings
) t1
GROUP BY t1.page_id
HAVING COUNT(page_id) = 1
```

Comment: That works just right. Thanks for your help, there're always so many ways to solve problems in SQL!

Comment: @Morgan Sure thing.  The COUNT(DISTINCT ...) is definitely the better way to go, also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you are grouping by *both* page_id and string_id.

You can fix the problem by just grouping by page_id:

```
SELECT page_id, string_id
FROM lang_strings
WHERE string_id != 'content'
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

This returns the `page_id`s that have only one row.  So, they have only one string id.

If you mean that string id takes on only one value, but there can be multiple rows, then I would recommend the following `having` clause:

```
where max(string_id) = min(string_id)
```

You can also use:

```
where count(distinct string_id) = 1
```

However, the max/min comparison usually performs better than the `count(distinct)`.

Comment: I should have seen that. It was the end of the day, what can you say? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
SELECT page_id FROM lang_strings
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(string_id) = 1
```

As you have not specified in question i am not getting why you are using 
`WHERE string_id != 'content'`